# How to reverse the array in typescript for the following data?

Tags: arrays, reverse

```
0:"Both"
1:"Prepaid"
2:"Recoverable"
```

How to reverse the above array in typescript?

Comment: Have I answered your question? If so, please mark my post as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

As stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse):

```
yourArray.reverse() // will return reversed array
```

It is JS, but the method must be also in TS

Comment: From the MDN link in this answer, please note "The reverse() method reverses an array in place and returns the reference to the same array" and "The reverse() method returns reference to the original array, so mutating the returned array will mutate the original array as well."

Answer (score 1):

Just Add `.reverse()`

```
yourArray.reverse()
```